# Tools to do VCF to MAF and MAF to VCF conversion?

Tags: vcf, variant-calling, maf

Normally, I would use the [vcf2maf](https://github.com/mskcc/vcf2maf) scripts to convert a VCF to a MAF (or vice versa).

This is great software, but on my system, perl scripts with dependencies are easy to break. (Here it uses VEP.)

Are there any other alternatives to this?

Comment: What do you mean by this: “on my system, perl scripts with dependencies are easy to break”?

Comment: @KonradRudolph In my experience, perl + bioinformatics dependencies is a nightmare. Our system admin keeps +12 versions of perl to deal with this. (I don't want to start fights with any perlverts, but it is tiresome in contrast to R/Python.)

Comment: Interesting, I’m not sure I understand why. At any rate, R definitely has the same, or worse, problem: it fundamentally can’t handle multiple package versions (unlike Python).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'd agree with that assessment. You're welcome to discuss this with my team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this python script [vcf2maf.py](https://github.com/cbare/vcf2maf)

Comment: Ironically, from their README: "This code is no longer maintained. Please have a look at: mskcc's vcf2maf."

Answer (score 6):

You can use annovar to annotate the vcf, then convert it to maf using the function `annovarToMaf` of [maftools](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/maftools.html) bioconductor package.

Comment: Can you include links to the tools and packages you refer to.